# Cannot import pymc3 module due to geweke

Tags: python, pymc3

I've tried installing it on a separate env and installing `arviz` separately. The `import pymc3 as pm` will not work.

```
AttributeError: module 'arviz' has no attribute 'geweke'
```

Comment: It has to do with the incompatibility of updated and not updated packages and Python. You can read about some of the working options here: https://discourse.pymc.io/t/attributeerror-module-arviz-has-no-attribute-geweke/6818/4

Answer (score 5):

It looks like [the issue](https://discourse.pymc.io/t/attributeerror-module-arviz-has-no-attribute-geweke-in-google-colab/6821/6) is related to the version of python (3.6) you are using and a dependant library pyMC use called `arviz`.

Make sure you uninstall the old version and follow the following steps to reinstall everything.

Uninstall using :

- `pip uninstall Theano Theano-PyMC PyMC3`

Make sure you remove theano left overs by running :

`sudo rm -fr  the_python_path_u_are_using/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano`

And then install arviz with :

- `pip install arviz==0.10.0`

And finally, install pymc3 again.

`pip install pymc3`

Try again and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your environment

For Anaconda:
Uninstall “arviz”
Use:
conda uninstall arviz

Now, install the latest version of “arviz”
For today, it is version 0.11.1
Use:

```
conda install arviz==0.11.1
```

For Non Anaconda environments:
Uninstall “arviz”
Use:
pip uninstall arviz
Now, install the latest version of “arviz”
Use:

```
pip install arviz==0.11.1
```

Answer (score 1):

My environment: Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.7.10

I have similar problem, after read this error at https://discourse.pymc.io/t/attributeerror-module-arviz-has-no-attribute-geweke/6818/4. The following commands solve the problem of `AttributeError: module 'arviz' has no attribute 'geweke'`

```
pip uninstall arviz
pip install arviz==0.11.0
pip install pymc3==3.10.0
```