# pymc3 error. AttributeError: module 'arviz' has no attribute 'geweke'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, pymc3

I got the following error:
`AttributeError: module 'arviz' has not attribute 'geweke'`.

See the attached full stack trace below:
[image: error stack trace]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Next time, please provide the code as a snippet instead of a linked image. You can use a snippet by using the \`single line\` or triple for multi-line \`\`\` multi-line \`\`\`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot import pymc3 module due to geweke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67349537/cannot-import-pymc3-module-due-to-geweke)

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though the `pymc3` module on your computer is not configured correctly. I would try reinstalling `pymc3` with `pip install --force-reinstall pymc3`. If you have python3 and python2, then you may have to use `pip3` instead of `pip`.