# How could it be that Python module `arviz` has no attribute `plots`?

Tags: python, arviz

I tried to run this program:

```
import pymc3 as pm
import theano.tensor as tt
import scipy
from scipy import optimize
```

but I got in return some non understandable comment:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_38164/4136381866.py in <module>
----> 1 import pymc3 as pm
      2 import theano.tensor as tt
      3 import scipy
      4 from scipy import optimize

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymc3\__init__.py in <module>
     70 from pymc3.model import *
     71 from pymc3.model_graph import model_to_graphviz
---> 72 from pymc3.plots import *
     73 from pymc3.sampling import *
     74 from pymc3.smc import *

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymc3\plots\__init__.py in <module>
     26 
     27 # Makes this module as identical to arviz.plots as possible
---> 28 for attr in az.plots.__all__:
     29     obj = getattr(az.plots, attr)
     30     if not attr.startswith("__"):

AttributeError: module 'arviz' has no attribute 'plots'
```

**Note that**:

`arviz` was downloaded: `conda install -c conda-forge arviz`

`pymc3` was downloaded: `conda install -c conda-forge pymc3`

`theano-pymc` was downloaded: `conda install -c conda-forge theano-pymc`

So, please, how could I provide this attribute `'plots'` to this module `'arviz`'? I really dont understand how to solve this `AttributeError`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pymc3 error. AttributeError: module 'arviz' has no attribute 'geweke'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69156546/pymc3-error-attributeerror-module-arviz-has-no-attribute-geweke)

Comment: J am sorry, but the use of `pip install --force-reinstall pymc3` as suggested in the  post you are linking to, does not work.